# How to clear contents of file with batch script

Tags: php, windows, batch-file, iis, iis-7.5

I have a self-hosted local website (on W10) with a little chat application. The chat history is saved to a `log.html` file, and i want to clear it out with a batch script.
I know that on the Ubuntu Shell, it is as simple as `> log.html` but on Windows, that doesn't work.
 
I also found `nul > log.html`, but it says **access denied**
I also don't want to use a powershell script as i have to change executing rules and it takes nearly a minute.
So, my question is:
**Is there a way that i can empty `log.html` with a batch script that doesn't stay open for longer than 20 seconds?**

Or, I don't mind if there is a way to use something *php-related* to clear it daily. I'm using IIS on Windows 10v1803 if that helps.

Comment: `copy /Y nul log.html`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you want is:

```bat
TYPE NUL > log.html
```

…or as possible alternatives:

```bat
BREAK>log.html
```

```bat
CLS 2>log.html
```

```bat
CD.>log.html
```

*Technically they're not emptying the file they're writing a new file which overwrites the existing one.*

Comment: I use `cd . > file.txt` to create an empty file because it don't use any "esoteric" feature, like `break` command or `nul` device: everybody knows what `cd .` does (and that it don't display any result). This also works: `rem/ > file.txt`

Comment: @Aacini, I have added the `CD` version to the alternatives in my answer, because it is very short and, as you said, easy to understand.

Answer (score 2):

This will delete the file and re-create it, and instantly close, so pretty much what you're wanting. Replace `"Desktop"` with the file path to the file, and place this `.bat` in the same folder as your `log.html`:

```
@echo off
cd "Desktop"
del "log.html"
echo. 2>log.html
```

Comment: Since you are using the simple redirection `>` the del command is superfluous. Also the `cd "Desktop"` wihout knowing where the file is located and as a relative reference. Otherwise using the empty error output stream to create a zero byte file is clever +1.